how to avoid passing through extra data fields when downstream service interface changes without notice
We are building a system consisting of multiple micro-services. We have a Node.js BFF gathering and organize data from downstream services then returns back to client side. If the downstream service API changes and contained extra data field, our BFF may pass that new field to the client, which is undesired due to info leak risk. For example, the original User type provided by downstream may be
User { name, age }, and our BFF pass through the data as it is. If the downstream started to contain the address field, we are leaking user's info.
What are the best practices to prevent this happening? I know GraphQL asks client to define the exact fields they want and only return those fields. But this asks a lot code change in the client side. An ideal solution should be, there is no need to change client side code but just Node.js side.
Another potential solution I'm thinking is to use the joi.js and create a middleware for the Node.js side, and requires each endpoint to have a pre-defined schema and clean up the data before returns.
I'm wondering if there are other viable solutions? We expect least amount of effort to change our current code.
